# Cycle images in a UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I have some images in an array and I add the images onto a scroll view, but I want to show only 3 images on the screen at any given time. The screen has arrows on both sides with 3 images in the middle and upon clicking the arrow, the next image replaces the third image, the third image replaces the second, the second replaces the first and the first leaves the screen.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds you want behavior that is like paging, except you page by a fraction of the scrollview bounds, rather than the whole thing.

Maybe you could create a UIScrollViewDelegate, implementing this method:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

And if the position is not a multiple of your image width, animate the position to the nearest boundary.  If you have too many images to load into the scrollview all at once, well then you'll have to do some extra tricks.

Answer (score 0):

In last year's WWDC there was a session exactly on this very topic. If you are enrolled in the developer program, check out `Session 104 - Advanced Scroll View Techniques` in WWDC11.